# Referencing private helper class from activity

Tags: java, android, class, constructor

I need to use some methods from a helper class but having trouble when I try to create a object of the helper class in my activity.

```
HelperClass helper = new HelperClass();
```

When I do the above I get an error saying I need to make the visibility of Helper() default.
Here is the relevant part of the helper class.

```
public class HelperClass {

private static HelperClass helperClass;
private String list;

private HelperClass() {
    initialiseHelper();
}
```

When I take out the private in the HelperClass it is fine but I do not want to edit this class. Is there a way around this?

Comment: There should be another constructor that's not `private`. Use that one.

Comment: If this class is in the same package, than you can make the constructor package private or add a public "factory method", i. e. a static method to create an object of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to apply **Singleton** pattern, but you're missing the `getInstance()` method, which should look like this:

```
public static synchronized HelperClass getInstance() {
    if (helperClass == null) {
        helperClass = new HelperClass();
    }
    return helperClass;
}
```

Now you should use this method everywhere you want to reference an instance of `HelperClass`. Hope this helps.

Comment: How would I call this from my activity?

Comment: @Amanni, `HelperClass helperClass = HelperClass.getInstance();`

Answer (score 0):

If You want have private constructor You can make singleton from HelperClass.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Helper` class does not have a `public` constructor as you have marked it `private`.

Or

```
public HelperClass{

   private HelperClass(){
   // do some stuff
   }

   public static HelperClass newInstance(){
       new HelperClass();
   }
}
```

Or use **Singleton Pattern**